# Swift returning a function with CloudKit data

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, function, cloudkit

I have a CloudKit database that contains records in this format...

- Title: String
- Subtitle: String
- Location: Location

I'm working with a sample Swift project that places Annotations on a map. The project stores the Annotation data in an Array of functions that is just manually typed in a class file.  Here is the code from that file...

```
class POIService {
static let sharedInstance = POIService()

lazy var pointsOfInterest: Array<POI> = {
    return [
        POI(
            title: "First interesting place.",
            subtitle: "This place is great",
            coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(
                latitude: 49.8519574378154,
                longitude: -97.2117918551222
            )
        ),
        POI(
            title: "Fifth interesting place.",
            subtitle: "I don't know where I am...",
            coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(
                latitude: 49.8141108489216,
                longitude: -97.1298990909147
            )
        )
    ]
}()}
```

Rather that using this data to create the annotations, I would like to be able to return the Array of functions programmatically using my CloudKit data.
I can get the data without any problems, but being somewhat new to programming I can't really wrap my head around how I would return the array of functions.  I've tried to create a function that returns another function, to be able to create the array, but I end up getting lost.

Here is a link to the project on github (i'm not the author)...
https://github.com/Winnipeg-iOS-Developers/InterestingPoint

I'm just trying to return points on the map from my CloudKit database instead of using their sample data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm really trying to learn as much as possible from this project, but this has me totally stuck.

Thanks

Comment: Also worth noting, I could very well be completely wrong about what I'm thinking is happening.  It looked to me like an array of functions, but it may not be.  As I said, this is all a ways over my head. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if i get you. do you mean something like

```
func someFunc(a:String, b:Bool)->String {
    return "Test"
}
var arrayOfFunctions : [(String, Bool)->String] = [
    {(param1 : String, param2: Bool) -> String in
        "Hello"
    },
    {(param1 : String, param2: Bool) -> String in
        "Bye"
    },
    someFunc 
]
```

the syntax for a function type is `(param1:Type1,...,paramN:TypeN)->ReturnType`

the members are simply closures or references to functions

Comment: Not sure that I understand the code.  I"m just trying to create an array of functions, that is filled with my cloudKit data.  I assume I'm going to have to do a for loop to create the functions with the CK data?

Comment: can you be more specific in your question, e.g. using pseudo code. that do do mean by "array of functions"

Comment: To setup an annotation on the map view I need an array of annotations.  Each item in the array is a function which returns the annotation data.  The function looks like this `annotation(title: string, subtitle: string, coordinate: location)`   So I need to be able to return an array of those functions to show all annotations on the map.  At least thats what I think I need.  As I said, I'm not sure as I haven't been working with code very long.

Comment: I tried to paste my CloudKit code in but it won't fit in the comment section.